# UI Concept Ideas

Tags: .net, xml, user-interface

I'm having trouble in finding ideas for a GUI concept and hopefully, you guys can help me out.

Dealing with objects, that will eventually get serialized to xml, I can show at least what the final result will look alike, the need is to create a useful and intuitive GUI for this:

```
<conditions>
  <condition id="1" hint="this"/>
  <condition id="2" hint="and that">
    <condition id="2.1" hint="or that"/>
  </condition>
</conditions>
```

So the basic idea is, that nested elements have an OR connection, while siblings have an AND connection.(Yes, that is not optimal, but it is what I got to use).

On the first throw, before nested elements were planned, it was quite easy to use a TreeView and just check the items, that were conditions, but now another hierarchy layer is added.

So how would you design a GUI element for such a thing?

Comment: Where would the GUI for this be running - Desktop, mobile, tablet, web?

Comment: Currently it will be GUI in .NET Winforms, later a part of a web-project.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble because your design is fundamentally flawed.

Using hierarchical subordination to represent logical OR is extraordinarily unnatural and precludes the natural use of containment as a way of expressing compound conditions.

Try this instead:

```
<condition type="or">
  <condition type="and">
    <condition hint="this"/>
    <condition hint="and that">
  </condition>
  <condition hint="or that"/>
</condition>
```

Or, better yet:

```
<or>
  <and>
    <term hint="this"/>
    <term hint="and that">
  </and>
  <term hint="or that"/>
</or>
```

You'll then find that TreeView will again work fine.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sadly, this is not my design and I have to deal with it.

Comment: Push back. Your users deserve better, and this pig doesn't deserve lipstick.